# jboss5 class loader problem with spring and hibernate trying to parse applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

I am using Jboss5 and I'm trying to utilize Hibernate and Spring to load in a spring dao. I'm getting an exception which seems to point to an incompatibility in jars but I'm not quite sure what is going on. I've done quite a bit of searching and I can't seem to find something specific to this besides change JBOSS versions. I am wanting to know if anyone has had any similar issues or found a way to get around this. Should I not be including the spring and hibernate jars in my ear?

> Unexpected exception parsing XML
>   document from class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]; nested
>   exception is java.lang.LinkageError:
>   loader constraint violation: when
>   resolving method
>   "javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.setEntityResolver(Lorg/xml/sax/EntityResolver;)V"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader)
>   of the current class,
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/DefaultDocumentLoader,
>   and the class loader (instance of
>   ) for resolved class,
>   javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder,
>   have different Class objects for the
>   type org/xml/sax/EntityResolver used
>   in the signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a copy of one of the XML API JARs in your WAR or EAR, like Xerces, `xml-apis`, or something like that. This will clash (violently) with JBoss's own.

Make sure your WAR/EAR has none of its own copies of the `javax.xml` libraries in its `lib` directory.

Comment: Yes, this was it. I removed the hibernate dependencies from my pom.xml and then everything worked. Thanks!